# Do oil-rich, wealthy Gulf countries have any local nationalist movements?

Tags: political-theory, nationalism, gulf-states

Do oil-rich, wealthy Gulf countries have any nationalist movements that are specific to their own countries, such as Qatari or Emirati (UAE) nationalism? How strong are these nationalisms compared to other nationalisms, such as French or Indian nationalism?

Comment: I'm guessing by "local nationalism" you mean to distinguish from macro-nationalism like pan-Arabism? The line isn't too easy to draw in some cases (like "pan-"Germanism).

Comment: I'm DV for the goal-shifting. I see you also removed Saudi from the question, after I answered.

Comment: @Fizz, *I'm guessing by "local nationalism" you mean to distinguish from macro-nationalism like pan-Arabism?* --- Yes.

Comment: @Fizz, Coz, you focused only on one country and left others completely.

Comment: These nations exist peacefully without much discontent - what makes you think the citizens don't have and cherish their national identity and aren't nationalists?

Comment: You shouldn't change the question - it is unfair to someone who has answered earlier.

Comment: The edit by JonatahnReez from nationalism to nationalist movements is probably even further away that where the Q started..

Answer (score 3):

There was and probably still [is](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43123948) plenty of internal tribalism in Saudi Arabia. Some authors [cosider](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.3138/9781442654075-016/pdf) tribalism a precursor of nationalism or primitive form thereof.

As for nationalism proper, it kinda [depends](https://academic.oup.com/book/687/chapter-abstract/135368804?redirectedFrom=fulltext) how broadly you want to define the term. Some see it as distinct from religious fundamentalism, but some a close connection between religious revival (like Wahhabism, which was a substantial ideological component in the creation of Saudi Arabia) and [less religious] nationalism. Nowadays, religiously inspired divisions have certainly contributed to the gulf countries involvement in the war in Yemen.

Iraq [might](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_reserves_in_Iraq) qualify as oil rich to some extent too, and under Saddam it saw its own form of nationalism, a combination of religious and socialist-authoritarian ideologies, IIRC. And military expansionism that Iraq under Saddam certainly exhibited is sometimes associated with nationalism.

Comment: Iraq is a poor country.

Comment: @user366312: well, you've edited in "wealthy" after I answered your Q.

Comment: @user366312 Was Iraq really that poor before the first Gulf war?

Comment: @Philipp, Yes, it was poor.

Comment: @Philipp - No, Iraq was a relatively wealthy and prosperous arab state under Saddam Hussein.

Comment: I was curious so I looked up gdp per capita for other arab nations in 1980:
-Iraq $3,850
-Iran $2,439
-Saudi Arabia  $17,655
-Oman $5,358
-Libya $13,450
-Kuwait $20,966
-Syria $1,422
-Egypt $580
-Jordan $1,695
 
For comparison:
-United States $12,553

So was Iraq wealthy? Perhaps compared to Iran, Syria, Egypt and Jordan, but certainly not compared to Saudi Arabia, Kuwait and Libya.

Source: https://www.imf.org/external/datamapper/NGDPDPC@WEO/OEMDC/ADVEC/WEOWORLD

Answer (score 2):

As the Q was edited (after I wrote the other answer) to remove Saudi and focus on Qatar and UAE, yes, they have their own forms, in particular the UAE [had](https://repositorio.ual.pt/bitstream/11144/5671/1/08-EN-vol13-n2-art05.pdf) to "come up with something" (according to some authors) due to how it was founded/formed.

> The United Arab Emirates (UAE) gained independence in 1971 through the unity of several sheikhdoms. This unification was initially more of a formality, undertaken to ensure the political independence and recognition of the state. However, once the UAE’s federal structure became a reality, the state needed to increase loyalty to the federal state. This study examines why the UAE needed to construct a common “Emirati” identity and how it went about building it. It argues that, like other nation-states, the UAE attempted to create an identity encompassing its citizens by excluding other historical and geographic identities; it aimed to purify its population via an attempt to show that UAE “expats” and “citizens” are completely distinct from each other. Therefore, this study examines both the UAE’s pre-independence cosmopolitanism and its post-independence national law and state targets in purifying the nation, a process exacerbated by high-level tension between the federal state and the emirates. Furthermore, this study deals with using symbols in identity construction via state-sponsored initiatives. In the case of the UAE, these symbols include the myth of founding fathers, ethnic symbols, and other heritage matters, all of which are examined with reference to major theoretical works on modern nationalism such as Imagined Communities, Invention of Tradition, Banal Nationalism, and Ethno-Symbolism.

Additionally, the UAE also has a large influx of migrant workers, so they even have official [pages](https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/social-affairs/preserving-the-emirati-national-identity) on [ahem]
"preserving the national identity", where it's also said that the migrants outnumber the citizens 10:1.

And some (foreign) [commentary](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/mec/2018/12/11/national-identity-and-the-emirati-state/) on how that's done, on an ideological level:

> The imposition of the concept of ‘nation-state’ in the Gulf during the latter 20th century (as also occurred across the wider region) represented a sharp and largely artificial departure from the peninsula’s historically tribal socio-political structures. In this way, nation-building has not relegated but rather has maintained – perhaps even heightened – the salience of the tribal.
>
> This tension between the state’s pursuit of the construction of a coherent identity at the national level, versus the reality of sub-national identities, is reflected across the region. In this context, the role of heritage and nation-building initiatives can be seen to reflect and institutionalise, rather than re-dress and overcome, the existing and contested distributions of power in society. Heritage projects in the UAE embody a particular emphasis on ‘Arabian Bedouin desert traditions’ and a ‘Bedouin-style cultural past’, despite the fact that the majority of the country’s nationals belong to settled (and largely urban) communities.

---

As for Qatar, despite being a smaller country, its identity building is perhaps even [more complicated](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/21534764.2020.1854273). Not only is the unification of its tribes (c. 1860s) a "founding myth", but there are complicating factors that Qatari citizenship itself is legally divided between those that were so before 1930 (!) and those who were granted citizenship later, never mind the more recent non-citizen migrants, i.e. it also shares the same 10% citizens issue (with UAE). There's also the complicating factor of the evolving conflicts with Saudi Arabia, [so](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/21534764.2020.1854273)...

> The scale and scope of the conflict have reduced the salience of khaliji identity –– the social recognition among Gulf citizens that they share heritage, culture, religion, and kinship ties across national boundaries –– and opened the door for increased expression of state-specific nationalism. [...]
>
> In Qatar, nation-building narratives do more than address the inherent inequalities and destabilizing effects of the distributive system. These narratives are also aimed at smoothing the demographic divisions within Qatari society. Qatari citizens are generally estimated to comprise only about 10% of the country’s total population. [...]
>
> Citizenship is often conflated with national identity, but the two are distinct concepts. While national identity may be ethnic or civic, and inclusive or exclusive, citizenship laws in the Gulf often officially sanction inequalities between citizens. Qatar’s 2005 Nationality Law divides citizens into two tiers, national (Article 1) and naturalized (Article 2), based on whether the family resided in Qatar **before 1930**. Al-Kuwari argues that the nationality law “paves the way for this transformation of citizens into inhabitants who enjoy none of their rights of citizenship. It does this by permanently depriving citizens who have acquired Qatari citizenship (about one third of all citizens) and their descendants of all political rights”. The two tiers of citizenship do indeed come with different political rights; naturalized citizens may have their citizenship revoked more easily (Articles 11–12) and are ineligible to be candidates or even vote for the legislative body, which in Qatar would mean the national Advisory (Shura) Council (Article 16). Further, the children of naturalized citizens retain this second-tier legal status –– as they can never become “national” citizens (Articles 1–2), these legal inequalities are passed down from generation to generation.
>
> Why the date of 1930? In the early 1900s, Qatar’s economy was almost entirely based on the pearling industry. The collapse of the pearling trade in the 1920s occurred because of Japan’s introduction of cultured pearls, and it devastated the Qatari economy. Between one-third and one-half of the population of Qatar is estimated to have emigrated in the 1920s and 1930s due to the difficulty of finding enough food and work to survive.
> Among these emigrants are the hawila, who built businesses in Persia or elsewhere for several decades before returning to Qatar in the 1940s and 1950s when the economy began to improve, in large part due to oil exports. When they did return –– along with the ajam, who immigrated to Qatar from Persian origins at around the same time –– they were classified with second-tier citizenship, a legal division that has solidified social divisions among Qataris. Family-enforced restrictions on marriage choices are one of the most tangible modern consequences of this citizenship law.
>
> These cultural and geographic divisions within Qatari society give increased importance to the propagation (and reception) of state-crafted narratives of Qatari identity and heritage. Museums have been a central part of Qatar’s nation-building efforts since the country’s formal independence in 1971. As Al-Mulla notes, within three months of his ascension to power, Amir Shaikh Khalifa bin Hamad Al Thani (r. 1972–95) began archaeological excavations and project planning of the country’s first national museum. Establishing a state museum and collection was a deliberate effort to archive, protect, and represent Qatari cultural heritage and history at a time when there was no historical and cultural repository for the nation. The process, nonetheless, necessitated a political use of Qatar’s history and cultural materials in order to construct a narrative of nationalism.
>
> [...] since 2007, the Qatari state has been focused on a complete renovation and reconstruction of its national museum to align with an updated national narrative, one of a unified citizenry where coastal and desert lifestyles are combined to form a “dualistic lifestyle, in which Qataris moved back and forth between the desert and the coast depending on the seasons”. This focus on movement connects the lifestyle between the winter months, with herding and camping in the desert, and the summer months, when people settled on the coast and engaged in pearling, to create a “tribal modern” brand that unifies Qatari identity. As the head curator of this section of the museum explained in 2014, “We are Qatari people: We have our camels, but we also have our dhows [pearling boats]. We need the people to know this. We were not always Bedouin only, or only part of the fishing villages. We were all together. Part of the time we live here, part of the time we live there. We live the duality life”.

Despite this official narrative of unification, one person interviewed reflected on the popular conception of (racial) purity in Qatar:

> yeah, we do have tribalism, and I think you pride yourself on whether your tribe is purely Arab or a mixed tribe. Do you have blood from West Asia –– like Iran or Pakistan –– or are you fully Arab from Saudi Arabia? I feel like that does play a role in life here. The more Arab you are, the more “pure” you are.

And another's

> description of the families who “came in the last forty years” and “only started migrating to Qatar when they saw that they could live there and the discovery of oil brought in even more people” is the common societal trope that allowed for the creation and continuation of the Nationality Law as it currently stands. This codification of two tiers of citizenship is thus being solidified in the national museum’s “unity” narrative.

Besides that only half-convicing aspect, there's also the royal/ruling-family [aspect](http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/106263/) that is prevalent some Gulf countries and it is fused with the national identity, at least in the official discourse:

> Saudi Arabia is, after all, the only country in the world named after its ruling family – a testament
> to the primacy of family in the region, signalling also the predominance of ascriptive
> identity over, for instance, ideological affiliation as is the case in more democratic states.
> Some scholars have gone so far as to dub the GCC states ‘families with flags’, demonstrating
> how central tribalism remains to political and social life in these states. Indeed, the
> GCC monarchies have been remarkably effective in constructing modern nation states
> within only decades of their establishment due to their ability to gain central authority
> in the GCC states. In short, ‘[l]ike the regimes of seventeenth-century European absolutists,
> most of the regimes of the Middle East are centralized, personalistic, and actually or
> potentially coercive. These features are typical of (perhaps even required by) the project
> of state-formation.’
>
> Nationalism throughout the GCC [Gulf Cooperation
> Council (GCC) states] remains linked to members of ruling families, whose
> photos are ubiquitous in the region. National Days are one important means of emphasising
> the personalistic nature of nationalism inside the GCC monarchies: all have the
> ruling family at their centre. Such modes of emphasising monarchical authority help to
> fuse loyalty to the ruling family with loyalty to the state. Going beyond the flagging that
> Michael Billig describes, across the GCC, a variety of ‘national’ markers have become
> inextricably linked to the ruling family, making it nearly impossible for a citizen to support
> the state without backing the regime. Indeed, across the UAE, 2018 was commemorated
> as the Year of Zayed, since it marked 100 years since the birth of Shaykh Zayed bin Sultan
> al-Nahyan, the country’s first president and widely considered its founding father. Events
> were held across the emirates through the Higher National Committee for the Year of
> Zayed, demonstrating how institutionalised and how sustained the celebration of the
> former ruler was. In a less institutionalised way, the image of Qatari Emir Shaykh Tamim
> bin Hamad al-Thani has become more prominent throughout Qatar after Bahrain, Egypt,
> Saudi Arabia and the UAE cut ties with the country in June 2017; images of the emir remain
> a symbol of Qatar’s resilience against external threat, with the image of ‘Tamim al-Majd’,
> drawn by a local artist, having become particularly popular. Oman’s Sultan Qaboos, who
> held a variety of positions in the government, was also widely seen as the father of the
> nation, and thus was mourned for 40 days following his death in January 2020, showing
> how widely the figure himself was associated with the state.

So, it is a somewhat complicated topic, with ethno-nationalism and royalism combined.